# Change default position of "{" in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, coding-style

I started using VS2010 and C# and the " **{** "s are weird. If I create a new project or autocreate a function its always like:

```
function()
{
    //
}
```

So I have to edit it several times. How to change that to normal? Normal is for me:

```
function() {
    //
}
```

I know thats not that important, but I dont like it. Im sure there is a way to change that, is there? Thank you

Edit: Thank you all for the fast answers. Maybe another thing that I would like to know - if I change the rules for the **{** and creating a big project. And if other people want to work on it too (on their own VS2010), can they change somehow the **{** back to normal without any problems or just manually?
Edit2: Nope, I think its not possible.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question and I'm being border-line subjective, but I always recommend using the brace notation that is standard for the language you are programming in.  In Java and JavaScript, having { on the same line is standard.  In C,C++, and C#, having { on a newline is standard.  To each his own, but it is something worth noting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an option in visual studio:

Tools => Options => Text Editor => C# => Formatting => New Lines => New Line options for braces.

You can choose this for a type/method etc separately.

Comment: Note for other readers: I nearly missed this the first time I looked in VS2010.  After selecting New Lines, you need to scroll the top left pane to the top to see branch 'New line options for braces'.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Tools->Options...->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->New Lines`. You can change the settings there.

Comment: There's no Settings menu option in VS2010

Comment: Alright, Options :P though i would worry if someone got stuck on that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you look over the [C# Coding Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) before proceeding too much further. Putting the braces on a new line will seem strange to someone coming from a Java background, but this is a standard practice within the C# community and seasoned engineers having to inspect / debug / update your code in the future will appreciate you maintaining that practice.

Comment: I've always wondered why MS ignores this convention sometimes (.designer partial classes in ASP.NET for example).